# Как создать две таблицы в БД

Tags: c#, sqlite3, xamarin, maui

Имеется модель1 "Тренировка" которая включает в себя "Название тренировки" и "Список упражнений"
Имеется модель2 "Упражнение", которая включает в себя "Название упражнения" и "Вес".

```
 public class TrainingModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ExerciseModel> exercisesList { get; set; }

}
public class ExerciseModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

При такой реализации появляется ошибка "System.NotSupportedException: "Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1". Как я понимаю, что список не является допустимым типом для значения базы данных SQLite.
Как создать связь между этими двумя таблицами.
Проект MAUI использую библиотеку SQLite-net-PCL в C#

Comment: Используйте современные решения, такие как EF, которые сделают все почти за вас, вам лишь создать класс описывающие базу, и сделать миграцию, все..

Comment: Навесить атрибут `[OneToMany]`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29005182/5045688. Документация у этой библиотеки довольно бедная. Придётся выискивать информацию по крупицам. Как вариант, смотреть на гитхабе код в папке tests.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен таким образом. Ссылка на более подробную документацию: https://github.com/media-tools/sqlite-net-extensions/tree/master.
Установил расширение для атрибутов: SQLiteNetExtensions.
Модели:

```
public class TrainingModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<ExerciseModel> Exercises { get; set; }

}
 public class ExerciseModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(TrainingModel))]
    public int TrainingId { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]     
    public TrainingModel Training { get; set; }

}
```

Методы для добавления в БД:

```
 database.InsertWithChildren(model);
```

Метод для получения данных с БД:

```
database.GetAllWithChildren<TrainingModel>();
```